# How to make a CSS rule act differently inside another div tag?

Tags: html, css

Let’s say I have a CSS rule:

```
.rule1 {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

I want this CSS rule to act differently inside another div tag, like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="rule1"></div> <!-- End of Rule1 -->
</div> <!-- End of Container -->
```

If this rule1 div is located inside the container div, I want `.rule1`’s background to be `#CCC`.

How do I specify this in CSS?

I have seen and tried something like this:

```
.container: rule1 {background:#CCC}
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.container .rule1 {  }
```

CSS nesting selector, meaning `.rule1` is inside `.container`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the colon:

```
.container .rule1 {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.rule1 {
     background:#FFF;
}
div.rule1 { /* if you want it applied just for divs with that class */
    background:#CCC;
}
.container .rule1 { /* if you want it applied to any child of .container */
    background:#111;
}

.container div.rule1 { /* if you want it applied to any child of .container that is only a div */
    background:#111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/SxRv3/)***

You would need to use specificity to target that rule when nested, and then set its definitions to `inherit` or to whichever alternative you were interested in.

So for this structure

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="rule1">rule1 nested</div>
</div>
<div class="rule1">rule1</div>
```

That would look like this

```
.rule1 {
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;
}
.container .rule1{
 background:inherit;/*or alternative definition*/
 color:inherit;/*or alternative definition*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container .rule{
     /*your valid css rule*/
}
```

Comment: `//` is not a valid CSS comment.